# ASP.NET equivalent of this PHP code (arrays)?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I am mainly programming in PHP, but for my school project I have to use ASP.NET(C#). Now I have this code which works in PHP:

```
$Data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $date = strtotime($row["Date"])*1000;
    $Data[] = array($date, $row["Data"]);
}
```

1. As you can see it's a 2D array, which is expanding, but the inner array always has two parameters. Now I have searched on the web and haven't found how to declare a expanding array in ASP.NET(C#).
2. Is there a replacement for strtotime in aspx?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given it's now C# and the datatypes [should come across through the reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime.aspx), the following should work:

```
// use a struct to store your retrieved information
public struct Details
{
  DateTime date;
  Object data;

  public Details(DateTime Date, Object Data)
  {
    date = Date;
    data = Data;
  }
}

// use List<T> to define a dynamically-sized list
List<Details> dataArray = new List<Details>();
while (reader.Read()) // query the database
{
  // add the information to the list as we iterate over it
  dataArray.Add(new Details(reader.GetDateTime("Date"),reader["Data"]));
}

// your new expansive array: dataArray.ToArray();
// converting an object to datetime: Convert.ToDateTime();
```

This also assumes you're using a [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) (though you could use almost anything to retrieve the information from SQL).

---

#### Update

Given the comments below, the information is retrieved from a database and then output to JSON. Because of the new requirement I am going to change the store format a bit. This gives the flexibility to continue using the JavaScriptSerializer while outputting to a format javascript can understand.

```
// make a list we can use
List<Object[]> details = new List<Object[]>();

// populate the data
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("<connection string>"))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("<query string>");
    SqlReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    .. go through the database
    while (reader.Read())
    {
      DateTime date = reader.GetDateTime("Date");
      Double data = reader.GetDouble("Data");

      // convert the datetime to unix time
      // http://www.epochconverter.com/
      var epoc = (date.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;

      details.Add(new Object[]{ epoc, data });
    }
}

// Now we serialize
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
String result = serializer.Serialize(details.ToArray());
```

And here's what I receive from `result` (for format anyways):

```
[
  [1297627668,0.7],
  [1297714068,1.1],
  [1297800468,0.1],
  ...
]
```

Comment: So this Convert.ToDateTime is equal to upper solution DateTime.Parse?

Comment: @JernejJerin: Yes, but it's implemented in the SQL Reader. You can also use Convert.ToDateTime, though DateTime.Parse will exception out should the information be invalid/unconvertable. You can also use DateTime.TryParse if you want it to carry on through invalid input (the function will return true/false if it could or could not convert).

Comment: @Brad Christie: I implemented your idea. The upper code I have implemented in Data.aspx.cs, then I call function (ReturnArray()), which iterates through reader and returns dataArray.ToArray(). I called that function from the parameter: string arrayJson = serializer.Serialize(ReturnArray()). But it returns empty result: [{},{}], on this example: dataArray.Add(new Details(DateTime.Parse("2010-05-01 00:00:00"), 5));
        dataArray.Add(new Details(DateTime.Parse("2010-05-01 00:10:00"), 6));

Comment: @JernejJerin: Ah, you're looking to serailize TO json eh? Should have made that a little clearer. ;-) Give me a little bit, and I'll update my answer (and I'll leave another comment to let you know it's been updated).

Comment: @JernejJerin: What's consuming the JSON data? Is a value of `{"date":"date(156266026"}` acceptable in the encoded result?

Comment: @Brad Christie: I am using the JSON data for flot graphs, in PHP the result is like this: TemperatureOUT = [[1297539900000,1.7],[1297540200000,1.7],[1297540500000,1.7],.... So it has to be in miliseconds.

Comment: @JernejJerin: Ah, so you want an array back. Just shy of writing your own serialization methods, this could get a little complicated. It may be best just to write the values out on your own in to a string. I'll write up a demo for you.

Comment: @Brad Christie: Thank you very much if you do that!

Comment: From flot API.txt: "The time series support in Flot is based on Javascript timestamps,
i.e. everywhere a time value is expected or handed over, a Javascript
timestamp number is used. This is a number, not a Date object. A
Javascript timestamp is the number of milliseconds since January 1,
1970 00:00:00 UTC. This is almost the same as Unix timestamps, except it's
in milliseconds, so remember to multiply by 1000!
"

Comment: @JernejJerin: My apologies for the delay. I kept going back and forth with how I wanted to go it. Finally, I went with a native parser, and just restructuring the information. Updated code is in my answer, let me know if you have any further issues.

Comment: Nice answer, although that magic number `621355968000000000` hurts my eyes. Why not something like `var epocOffset = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks;`

Comment: @JimMischel: I thought about it, but 1) I got it from the site and 2) I felt spinning up a new datetime object was more effort than a hard-coded value to subtract. ;-)

Comment: @Brad Christie: Thanks it works great with only one problem. The chart is drawn right, only the time is messed up. I guess this does not work right: var epoc = (date.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000;. I already tried some code that found on net: public static int DateTimeToUnixTimeStamp(DateTime time)
    {
        TimeSpan t = (time - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
        int timestamp = (int)t.TotalSeconds*1000;
        return timestamp;
    } And it is still wrong, I guess I'll have to dig harder:)

Comment: @JernejJerin: What version of .NET are you running?

Comment: @Brad Christie: Sorry for previous, just found out the solution:var epoc = (date.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000 + 60 * 60 * 1000; So it has to be divided by 10000 not 10000000 (probably because of ms?) and I have to add 60 * 60 * 1000 because I live in Slovenia and we are 1H ahead:) Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

First, how are you getting the data from the SQL database?  I'll assume that you're getting it as a collection of `DataRow` objects.

For storing the data, I would suggest using a list of tuples, as shown below.

```
List<Tuple<DateTime, string>> Data = new List<Tuple<DateTime, string>>();
// Somehow get a collection of rows into a results object
foreach (DataRow row in results)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(row["Date"]);
    Data.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, string>(dt, row["Data"]));
}
```

You can then access items in the list by index, and the individual fields as `Item1` and `Item2`:

```
DateTime dt = Data[0].Item1;
string itemData = Data[0].Item2;
```

Comment: I agree this look very good. But can I the use JavaScriptSerializer? Because I have to serialize it to JSON?

Comment: @JernejJerin: You should be able to, but you'll probably want to define the object structure in classes and deserialize to that. Otherwise, I believe, by default you'll end up with a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) of items, and (depending your structure) they may or may not be desired.